# Authorization Bearer Token - Get Identity Information

Tags: c#, claims-based-identity, bearer-token

When a user hits our other resources using their authorization bearer token, are we able to get his identity information from that in the back end c# library, without hitting our database again? We built the identity when crafting the token with the claims and such. I know the user name is in there, but I want some of the other items we added.

Comment: So you're building the claims object in your code? You can add as many child claims onto that as you want. Are you wondering about getting a claim from something like a WindowsIdentity instance?

Comment: Sorry I can't help here - but if I may ask, why do you need this?  Just curious...

Comment: Brannon, I am hoping to get all the identity information that we store about the user...so we can save information on updates/inserts about the user... who is logged in.

Comment: is this openid token in JWT format? You will be able to decode the token to get the basic info about the user.